# Docker on Windows 10 networking issue

Tags: windows, docker, hyper-v

I'm using Docker on a Window 10 laptop. I recently tried to get some code to run in a container to connect to another server on the network. I ended up making a Ubuntu  container and found the issue is a IP conflict between the docker network and the server resource (172.17.1.3).

There appears to be an additional layer of networking on the Windows Docker setup with isn't present on the Unix system, and the docker comments to "simply using a bridge network" doesn't resolve this issue.

```
docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "d60dd1169153e8299a7039e798d9c313f860e33af1b604d05566da0396e5db19",
        "Created": "2020-02-28T15:24:32.531675705Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Is it possible to change the subnet/gateway to avoid the IP conflict? If so how? I tried the simple thing and making a new docker network:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=172.15.0.0/28 --gateway=172.15.0.1 new_subnet_1
```

There still appears to have a conflict somewhere, I can reach other devices just nothing in 172.17.0.0/16. I assume guessing it's somewhere in the HyperV, vEthernet adapter, or vswitch.

**UPDATE 1**
I took a look at wireshark (PC level) with the new_subnet_1 network and I did not see these packets leave the vSwitch interface or the PC's NIC.
I did see this [Docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/bridge-with-docker-for-windows/30936/5) which is indicating an issue with the Hyper-V and V-switch that could be the issue.

Docker Engine v19.03.5
DockerDesktopVM created by Docker for Windows install

**UPDATE 2**
After several Hyper-v edits and putting the environment back together I check the DockerDesktopVm. After getting in from a privileged container I found that the docker0 network had the IP conflict. Docker0 is appears to be the same default bridge network that I was avoiding, because it is a pre-defined network it cannot be removed, and all my traffic is being sent to it.

Comment: There are many limitations with Docker on Windows (with Linux Containers). Docker Desktop for Windows can’t route traffic to Linux containers. However, you can ping the Windows containers. https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#i-cannot-ping-my-containers

Comment: How did you run your containers? Could you give an example to debug?

Comment: @matiferrigno for testing i'm using a ubuntu image created with `PS> docker run --net new_subnet_1 -ti ubuntu /bin/sh` once I'm in there I can use various tools to trouble shoot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several offshoots, and breaking my environment at least once, I found that the solution was easier then I had though.

1. Tuned off Docker Desktop Services
2. Added the following line to the `%userprofile%\.docker\deamon.json` file in windows 10

   ```
     ....lse,
     "bip": "172.15.1.6/24"   <<new non conflicting range
   }
   ```
3. Restarted Docker Desktop Service

Easy solution after chasing options in Hyper-V and the Docker Host Linux VM.

Comment: After 3 whole days of debugging, reconfiguring and changing Hyper-V network configurations, finally found this answer and it works! Thanks a lot! :)